# can we perform delete operations using pandas without reading the files

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, pandas

Can we do operations on a csv file or sql table without reading the file ,i.e without using read_csv or read_sql_table.

Basically i have a very large files and need to compare both files or tables and delete the common rows.

```
import pandas as pd

colnames=['email']

data= pd.read_csv("sample",names=colnames, header=None)

data1=pd.read_csv("sample1",names=colnames,header=None)

filter=data[~data['email'].isin(data1)]
```

I have been doing like this but as i m reading the csv files it is taking lot of time.
So is there any other way to perform this operation like we use "DELETE " operator in sql without reading the file.
Kindly help me please.

Answer (score 1):

You can do operations on files using the file object without reading it like -

```
f = open("xyz.csv")
for x in f:
    print(x, end=' ')
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but is their any way where i can do operations on table or file without reading in pandas, as we know pandas process is quite fast in speed and i work on billions of data ."Something like pd.read_sql_query"